# Withdrawing flags

Tags: feature-request, flagging

A few hours ago I flagged an answer as "not an answer". After a more careful reading, I realized I was mistaken. Unfortunately, the SE software seems not to provide the option to withdraw a flag (in contrast to the possibility of withdrawing a cast vote), therefore my question: is it posible to implement this functionality?

Comment: This is a fairly popular, and fairly frequent, feature request. See (and possibly vote on) [this meta.se question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500) and the numerous linked questions.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: If I want to vote for this feature, where do I do it? Or do I upvote the question?

Comment: An older post: [Can we cancel flags?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13418/can-we-cancel-flags)

Comment: @AlexM. Yes. Even if it had 1M upvotes there's still no guarantee that SE will ever actually implement it, but at least SE is aware of the popularity. (And, as far as I can see, they haven't [meta-tag:status-declined] it yet.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes, it has become possible now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags/281010#281010), both for questions and for answers: click on "flag" (below the already flagged post) and click on the dark blue button "Retract flag" below the list of flagging reasons.

Comment: Why did you post the same answer *four* times? You could have posted it just once and then marked the other three as duplicates...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: True that, and this is how I thought about it initially. Then I realized that I am always annoyed when I have to jump from link to link in order to reach some content that I am looking for, so I prefered to leave the answers on those pages for the convenience of the impatient readers like me.