# Can a flag be unflagged?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

If anyone flags any question and the flag is accepted as helpful flag. Then can it be unflagged by the user who flagged that question?

Reason for unflagging maybe that he unflag due to he thinks that it is an homework and question but after some conversation between question asker and question flagger, question flagger gets to know that it is not an homework question. So can the question flagger unflag the question somehow or anyhow?

Comment: See also: [Withdrawing flags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21372) and other posts [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/21372).

Answer (score 9):

Once a flag is handled (marked helpful, declined, or disputed), it cannot be retracted. Before they are handled, one can - since not too long ago - [retract one's flags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21372/withdrawing-flags/25334#25334).